# Search for specific string, only copy part of string into another textfile

Tags: python, string, file, search

I want my python program to search a text file for a specific portion of a string.
For example, my text file looks like this:

```
VERSION_1_0001
VERSION_2_0012
VERSION_3_0391
```

These are just examples. I want my python program to look for "VERSION_2_" but have it print out 0012 in another text file. Is that possible?

So far I just have this:

```
with open('versions.txt', 'r') as verFile:
    for line in verFile:
        if 'VERSION_2_' in line:
            ??? (I don't know what would go here so I can get the portion attached to the string I'm finding)
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Do you really want to check `'VERSION_2_' in line` instead of `line.startswith('VERSION_2_')`?

Comment: I'd rather check in line because in some text files, there are various characters before the actual VERSION.. So it might not always literally start with VERSION.

Comment: OK, you've definitely understood your data, thought it through, and made the right decision. Cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is about how to extract the part of the line after the last underscore:

```
 with open('versions.txt', 'r') as verFile:
    for line in verFile:
        if 'VERSION_2_' in line:
            # Split the line from the right on underscores and
            # take the last part of the resulting list.
            print line.rpartition('_')[-1]
```

If your question is about writing to a file:

```
with open('resultfile', 'w') as wFile:
    wFile.write(line.rpartition('_')[-1])
```

If you want to write all the results to the same file, open the file you want to write to outside the loop:

```
# It doesn't matter which `with` block is the outermost.
with open('resultfile', 'w') as wFile:
    with open('versions.txt', 'r') as verFile:
        for line in verFile:
            if 'VERSION_2_' in line:
                # Split the line from the right on underscores and
                # take the last part of the resulting list.
                wFile.write(line.rpartition('_')[-1])
```

Comment: +1. But you don't really need to pass `2` as the `maxsplit` here. You only want the rightmost value, so you can just pass `1`. Or, for simplicity, just leave it off.

Comment: @abarnert oh, I know, I was just cargo-culting under the assumption that splitting less is better. ;)

Comment: Awesome, this worked great. Is there a way for me to print it into another text file instead of on the screen? Also can you add a new line at the end of the 0012?

Comment: yes you can chakolatemilk ... its very trivial ... It seems to me that it might be a good exercise in research, and may help you learn python better.

Comment: Yup, I just did a little research and found out how. :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @kojiro: If splitting less is better, use `1` instead of `2` (or use `rpartition` instead of `rsplit`).

Comment: If I may ask @abarnert, what are the differences in using 1 or 2 for splitting?

Comment: @chakolatemilk Didn't I show you how to write to a separate file? … It's in my answer.

Comment: @kojiro Yes you did, I didn't see it until I refreshed the question. :) Thanks again!

Comment: @abarnert Yes, rpartition! Thanks for that.

Comment: @chakolatemilk the amount of splitting is microoptimizations you don't really need to worry about. Basically, we're trying to reduce the amount of effort Python spends on data that just gets thrown away. Use `rpartition` as abarnert says. (I've edited my answer.)

Comment: Alright, thanks for explaining and for all the help, everyone! Much appreciated.

Comment: @chakolatemilk: The best way to learn this stuff is to try it in the interactive terminal. Write `s='VERSION_2_0012'`, then see what `s.rsplit('_', 2)`, `s.rsplit('_', 1)`, `s.rsplit('_')`, and s.rpartition('_')` print out. And then, if it isn't obvious, try putting `[-1]` after each one. Or try it with `s='extra_stuff VERSION_2_0012'`, etc. Keep experimenting until you understand.

Comment: [REPLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) are the bees' knees.